# Redefining font sizes in LaTex

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, scripts

My intention is to set all font sizes to `\normalsize`. I can achieve this by redefining the command for each font size, using: `\renewcommand{\Large}{\normalsize}`

In this example, why the `scriptsize` is still the same no matter what?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{article}

\renewcommand{\large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\small}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\tiny}{\normalsize}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

This is the text body\footnote{This a footnote} with
some\textsuperscript{superscript} and some\textsubscript{subscript}.
Here are {\small different sizes} and {\Large another sizes}. Here is a
new footnote\footnote{With some {\small text} here {\scriptsize and
there}.}.


\subsection{Subsection}

\paragraph{Paragraph.}
And \tiny{another} one piece of text.


\end{document}
```

Output (all text in same size except `scriptsize`):
[image: font sizes sample]

Why happens this and how can I fix it so every font size is equal to `normalsize`?

Comment: This is due to the internal workings of `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript`.  They do not impose `\scriptsize` but rather do something similar to `${}^{\mbox{<text>}}$`.  This way `<text>` is scaled by `\scriptstyle` (as opposed to `\scriptsize`), which is a feature of math mode.  To rectify this, type `\textsuperscript{\normalsize ...}` or redefine `\textsuper/subscript` to add `\normalsize` to its argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To redefine `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` to apply `\normalsize` to its argument, we make use of the fact, that both call internal macros with eponymous names with an @.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,onecolumn]{article}
\renewcommand{\large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\Large}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\small}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\scriptsize}{\normalsize}
\renewcommand{\tiny}{\normalsize}
\makeatletter
\let\old@textsuperscript\@textsuperscript
\let\old@textsubscript\@textsubscript
\renewcommand{\@textsuperscript}[1]{%
  \old@textsuperscript{\normalsize #1}%
}
\renewcommand{\@textsubscript}[1]{%
  \old@textsubscript{\normalsize #1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section}

This is the text body\footnote{This a footnote} with
some\textsuperscript{superscript} and some\textsubscript{subscript}.
Here are {\small different sizes} and {\Large another sizes}. Here is a
new footnote\footnote{With some {\small text} here {\scriptsize and
there}.}.

\subsection{Subsection}

\paragraph{Paragraph.}
And \tiny{another} one piece of text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful, but the superscripts of the `footnote` command are still in their original size. How can I change them to `normalsize`?

Comment: @X.A.Corbal I also noticed that, see updated answer.